# Text before image

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new in the whole business and I have a small question.
I tried put text `(h3)` *before* image but it doesn't work for me no matter how hard I try,

I can use some help :)

This is what I tried,in addition tried to change the display and position but nothing helped.

```css
.prosc {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 4px;
}

.mo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.500em;
  line-height: 0.3;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-con">
  <h3 class="prosc">A <span class="pro">Pro</span>gramer</h3>
  <!-- This is the text that the picture blocks.-->
  <img class="mo" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Mountain-png" width="50px" height="40px">
  <!-- This one is the problem.-->
</div>
```

No error.

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the html portion?

Comment: `top: -50px;` in the `.mo` causes that image is shifted up by -50 pixels. Change it to `50px` and image is placed below text.

Answer (score 2):

Header elements, h1...h6 are block elements. Meaning that any content after them will start from a new line. If you need the image to follow directly after some text, use a `<span>` instead (which is an inline element). You can then use CSS to change the style of text, such as font-size, etc.

```html
<div class="top-con">
  <span class="prosc">A <span class="pro">Pro</span>gramer</span>
  <img class="mo" src="//placehold.it/40" alt="Mountain-png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Incredible useful for a lot more use cases than just this.

```css
.top-con {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-con">
  <h3 class="prosc">A <span class="pro">Pro</span>gramer</h3>
  <!-- This is the text that the picture blocks.-->
  <img class="mo" src="//placehold.it/40" alt="Mountain-png">
  <!-- This one is the problem.-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code like below:

```css
.prosc {
float:left;
}
.mo {
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-con">
  <h3 class="prosc">A <span class="pro">Pro</span>gramer</h3>
  <!-- This is the text that the picture blocks.-->
  <img class="mo" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Mountain-png" width="50px" height="40px">
  <!-- This one is the problem.-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always

```
  <h3 class="prosc">Image after text
    <img class="" src="">
  </h3>
```

put the image inside the h3 tag :p.